# Exception "unhandled AttributeError" 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

hi when i want to get text from QEditLine this error generate.

> **Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
>   'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'**
>
> **Class Code**

```
   def updateData(self):

        m1=self.a1.get()
        m2=self.a2.get()
        m3=self.a3.get()
        m4=self.a4.get()
        m5=self.a5.get()
        m6=self.a6.get()
        m7=self.a7_2.get()
        m8=self.a8_2.get()
        m9=self.a9_2.get()
        m10=self.a10_2.get()
        m11=self.a11_2.get()
        m12=self.a12_2.get()
        m13=self.a13_2.get()
        m14=self.a14_2.get()
        m15=self.a15_2.get()
        m16=self.a16_2.get()
        m17=self.search.get()

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("collage_App.db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute("UPDATE student_registration SET fname="+m2+",lname="+m3+" WHERE id="+str(m1))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.c.close()
        QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(),'Successful',"Updated Data Successfully! "+self.a1.get()+" ")
```

Comment: To get text from a QLineEdit you need to use `QLineEdit.getText()`.

Comment: @Heike  i change QLineEdit.get() to QLineEdit.getText() but Console Error **  Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'getText' **

Comment: @Heike  can you Solve this error?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, that should be `QLineEdit.text()`, not `QLineEdit.getText()` (so `m1=self.a1.text()` etc.)

Comment: now i again change and this is previously i set but this show me again same error    **Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: @Heike i set this **m1=self.a1.text()**  value not retrive from QLineEdit can tell me exactly error why this error appear? console error  **Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: @Heike have you idea about this? i have already set  m1=self.a1.text()  for all variable but console error same **Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: You have to change `.get()` to `.text()` for all your `QLineEdit` instances, not just `self.a1`. I would recommend reading the official [documentation of QLineEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)` to find out which attributes are available for QLineEdit.